# Finding the index of the key from given Valley_list

Tags: python

Input: first-line will contain the valley_list and the second line will contain the element key to be found in the list. No repetition of elements in the valley_list.

Output: index of the element key in the valley_list if it is present else -1.

Sample input:

```
list = [13, 11, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1, 14, 15, 16, 17] key to find = 8
```

Comment: Any attempt to think of a solution yourself ? What have you tried, where are u getting stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Imo a `try/except` block is the way to go:

```
lst = [13, 11, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1, 14, 15, 16, 17]
key = 8
try:
    index = lst.index(key)
    print(index)
except ValueError:
    print("{} not in the list.".format(key))
```

Additionally, do not name your variables `list`, `dict`, `tuple` or the like, it will shadow the builtin functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate` to return the index of the value that matches the searched value.

```
ls = [13, 11, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1, 14, 15, 16, 17] 
a = 8
def find_index(ls, num_to_find):
    for i, v in enumerate(ls):
        if v == num_to_find:
            return i
    return -1

print(find_index(ls, a))
```

Output

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in index function of list to find the index

```
a = [13, 11, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1, 14, 15, 16, 17] 
elem = 8

def find_index(lst, elem):
    if elem not in lst:
        return -1
    else:
        return lst.index(elem)

print(find_index(a, elem))
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that **No repetition of elements in the valley_list**, you can use `index` function.

```
def get_index(valley_list,key):
    try:
        return valley_list.index(key)
    except:
        return -1

valley_list=[13, 11, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1, 14, 15, 16, 17]
key=8
print(get_index(valley_list,key))
```

Comment: But, if the element is not present in list, it will throw an error instead of returning -1

Comment: @programmerpro, you are correct. I missed that. I have edited it considering it.